# CSS/HTML <form> breaks layout in chrome

Tags: html, css, forms

I've made a page of 'contact us' where the user should fill a form, and of course submit/send it.
Now, thing is that the moment I add `<form>...</form>` tags the layout breaks. It seems it happens only in chrome(not 100% sure yet).

However, surprisingly, if I instead of refreshing the page, use the menu(click contact us) the layout/design is just fine.
Seems the problem is caused by `<form>` tag. Without it the layout/design is fine

how it should be
[image: That's how it SHOULD look]
how it is with `<form>` tags
[image: The problem]

Please take a look if there is problem in my .css or .html.

CSS.css:

```
body{
    background-color: #80B2E6;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: medium;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav{
    height:3.5em;
}

#Content{
    padding:10px;
    width: 580px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#B89470;
}

#Content h2{
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
}

#Menu{
    background-color:#AD855C;
    display: block;
}

#Header{
    background-color:#AD855C;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#Logo{
    background-image:url('Library/Misc/LogoBG.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:100px
}

#Logo h2{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.Line{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 3.5em;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.MMLink{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#AD855C;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding: 1em;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}

a.MMLink:hover{
    background-color: #CEB69D;
    color:black;
}
a.MMLink:link{
    color:black;
}
a.MMLink:visited{
    color:black;
}
a.MMLink:active{
    background-color: #CEB69D;
    color:black;
}

#MenuLeft{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#MenuRight{
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.NewsFeed{
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.Form {
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

HTML Contactus.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            A page
        </title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css" />

    </head>
    <body>



        <div id="Header">
            <div id="Logo">
                <h2>  My Header </h2>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <div id="MenuLeft">
                    <a class="MMLink" href="Index.php">Home</a>
                    <div class="Line"></div>
                    <a class="MMLink" href="About.html">About</a>
                    <div class="Line"></div>
                    <a class="MMLink" href="Contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
                    <div class="Line"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="MenuRight">
                    <div class="Line"></div>
                    <a class="MMLink" href="Login.php">Login</a>
                    <div class="Line"></div>
                    <a class="MMLink" href="Signup.php">Sign-Up</a>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>




        <div id="Content">
            <h2>Contact us!</h2>
            <hr/>
            <p>
                That ironical, but if you've encountered a problem, a bug, or just want to contact us,
                <br/>
                please feel free to fill the next form.
            </p>

            <form>
            input fields go here
            <br/>
            </form>

            <p>some text2</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I might be 2cool4school but my JSfiddle of your code shows it how you want:  http://jsfiddle.net/74aaj5hx/

Comment: By the way - uppercase selectors are bad practice for CSS/HTML in general.  It isn't illegal or anything, just not meant for classes and IDs.  CSS selectors are case-sensitive and you put yourself at risk of unknown bugs in the future (i.e. - display is incorrect because you typed `#content` instead of `#Content` deep in your CSS file).  This issue can also happen because of your overuse of `id` selectors over classes.  Here is a great article on this - http://cssguidelin.es/#css-selectors.  Just food for thought from a fellow dev :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with your floats. Try adding `clear:both` to `#content`:

```
#Content{
    padding:10px;
    width: 580px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#B89470;
    clear:both:
}
```

On a side note I wouldn't use a seperate `div` for your vertial divders. Try using `border-left` and/or `border-right` on `.MMlink` instead. Also use `border-bottom` on your `<h2>Contact Us</h2>` and get rid of the `<hr />`

Here's how I'd tidy up your HTML with associated CSS changes: http://jsfiddle.net/kzww8fvb/

Comment: Tried the 'clear:both'. The layout is still broken but it looks a little different [link](http://s20.postimg.org/igemcb2j1/chromcsshtml_Prob_wrong2.png) also, thanks for the tip about the border, didnt thought using it instead of <hr/> & <div>